# CommandBindings / InputBindings and RoutedCommand.InputGestures

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I having trouble to understand some of the features in the RoutedCommand.
The RoutedCommand can be created and some input gesture can be attached:

```
HomeZoomPanCommand = new RoutedCommand();
HomeZoomPanCommand.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.F10, ModifierKeys.None));
```

Now I have to add the command to the CommandBindings collection which is quite clear to me.

Normally I would assume, that if I want to have F10 working on this command, I have to add a KeyBinding also to the InputBindings. This seems also clear to me.

But what happens in detail when I have the InputGestures already assigned to the RoutedCommand? I assumed that the gesture is automatically added to the InputBindings collection but it is obviously not.

For what reason are there two different ways. Does the InputGesture on the command really work or is it only to show it in the menu with any function?